# How can I prevent horizontal overflow?

Tags: html, css

Say I have a `<span>` that contains a very long sequence of numbers - long enough that it flows right off the right hand side of the page.

Most browsers would give me a scrollbar such that I can then scroll left and right.

How can I prevent the ability to horizontally scroll?

I've tried `body { overflow-x: hidden; }`, which works for desktop Chrome, but Chrome for Android retains the ability to horizontally scroll.

How can I absolutely guarantee no scrolling?

(I can adjust both HTML and CSS in this scenario, but I cannot use JS.)

Comment: show us your code

Comment: Apply `word-break: break-all` to the parent element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mind breaking the string of numbers?  If not, you can try `word-break:break-all`.  Here's the same HTML with and without `word-break`.

```css
#break {
  width: 300px;
  word-break: break-all;
  padding: 3px;
}

#noBreak {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="break">
  <span>123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789
</span>
</div>

<div id="noBreak">
  <span>123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd prefer not to break the string - the intended effect is for the numbers to flow off the edge of the page

Answer (score 0):

I think applying `overflow-x :hidden` works.

But unless you share the part of your code its difficult to answer to your requirement.

The better approach i would suggest is to use the `container` class of bootstrap 4, which makes the div responsive and you can keep this span inside that, or keep it in the div.

```html
<div class="wrapper container">
    <div class="row">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

The row class will always give -15px margins.
and container class gives padding of +15px.

Your question can get a clearer response if you can share the code snippet.